# How is the mixing of neutrinos related to eigenstates?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, weak-interaction

Can someone please explain to me why the following statement is true:

*"Neutrino mixing phenomena arise from the noncoincidence of energy-propagation eigenstate and the weak (interaction) eigenstate bases"*

This is a statement from an [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0101524) about sterile neutrinos, but this particular statement is regarding neutrinos in general (active and sterile).

**How was it deduced that because these eigenstates do not coincide, neutrinos must mix?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the case where there are only 2 kinds of neutrino's, since this is the easiest. When neutrino's propagate, they do so as the propagating eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. However, when detecting a neutrino we detect their mass eigenstate, not the propagating one.

Let the propagating eigenstates be $|\nu_1>$ and $|\nu_2>$ with mass eigenstates
$|\nu_e>$ and $|\nu_\mu>$. One can write one set of states as a linear combination of the other one (mixing):
\begin{align} 
|\nu_e> &= \cos(\theta) |\nu_1> + \sin(\theta) |\nu_2> \\
|\nu_\mu> &= -\sin(\theta) |\nu_1> + \cos(\theta) |\nu_2>  
\end{align}
This is a simple two-state system.
Let's say we prepare a state as $|\psi(0)> = |\nu_e>$, then this state will propagate according to
\begin{equation}
|\psi(\vec{x}, t)> = \cos(\theta) |\nu_1> e^{-ip_1 \cdot x} + \sin(\theta) e^{-ip_2 \cdot x} |\nu_2>
\end{equation}
where the evolution in the propagation eigenbasis is given by plane waves.

When writing $p_i \cdot x = E_i t - p_i L$ where $L$ is the traversed distance. It's actually already clear that the pobability of having a $|\nu_e>$ again, which is given by $|<\nu_e|\psi(\vec{x},t>|^2$ will depend on both $t$ and $L$. This is where the oscillations come in. Since the total probability stays 1, there will be values of $L, t$ for which one of the probabilities becomes 0 and the other 1.

Comment: So that means that because of the possibility of values between 0 and 1 there is always the chance that it oscillates between flavours?

Comment: Yeah, kinda, it oscillates between flavours because the probabilities change. One can have a 50% of finding it in either state or eg. 100% probability of finding an electron-neutrino at certain $(L,t)$.  
The fundamental reason is still that the mass eigenstates are not equal to the propagating ones.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I just have one last question:

So the coincidence of the eigenstates would happen if the dot product would result on the RHS going back to its original form?

Comment: No, even if the phase factors would vanish, there is still the $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. But the interference of both states do make it happen that at certain $(L,t)$ only one component remains. Normally one defines the relative phase between the 2 components so that only one components gets a phase factor. This phase factor is dependent on $E_1, E_2$ of course. A more detailed explanation and computation of this relative phase can be found in almost every particle physics book, I recommend Mark Thomson's Modern Particle Physics.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best analogy is birefringence (for 2 flavors). You have 2 orthogonal states of polarization (subbing for flavor), $H$ and $V$, and say electrons only interact with $H$ and muons with $V$, and never the twain shall meet.

Until they start propagating, in a birefringent medium. It has two eigenstates (the fast axis and the orthogonal slow axis, with two different indices of refraction). The index of refraction is sort of a like and effective mass, as it affects the speed of propagation. Moreover, $\Delta n$ plays the role of $\Delta m^2$, the difference in the masses (squared) of the mass eigenstates.

A "non-coincidence of eigenstates" means the crystal is not aligned:

$$ |H\rangle = \cos\theta|F\rangle+\sin\theta|S\rangle$$
$$ |V\rangle = -\sin\theta|F\rangle+\cos\theta|S\rangle$$

It would be a good exercise to fully develop the analogy, but in once $|H\rangle$ starts propagating, there is a phase shift between the $|F\rangle$ and $|S\rangle$ that cause the plane of polarization to oscillate between $H$ and $V$.

Throw in an third flavor, and of course, it gets a bit more complicated, but the idea is the same.